# Reference for a Linear Programming result

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming

I would like to know some reference for a result from Linear Programming.

The function $F(s)$ to be maximized depends linearly on the m+1 values, say $x_i$, and the constraints for $x_i$ are linear inequalities, say $x_i \geq 0$ plus another linear inequality constraint (Having m+2 constraints total). Then it is enough to consider those combinations for which m+1 constraints are satisfied as equalities.

I know all Linear Programming books analyze that, Strang or Dantzig book. But I would like to know if there is some particular theorem or some specific result that state this better, so I can use it as a reference.

Thank you!